# Ajax with JQuery on the Django Dev Server

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am putting together an Ajax request with JQuery (1.5) on a Django (1.2.5) site. I am working on the Dev Server currently because I plan on doing demonstrations before a full production roll out.

The javascript code in the template:

```
function postTest()
{
        $.post("/get_elections", { csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val() }, alertResult);

}

function alertResult(result)
{
    alert(result);
}
```

How it's called:

```
<a href="" onclick='postTest()'>Link</a>
{% csrf_token %}
```

The Ajax view:

```
def get_selections(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        message = "This is an XHR GET request"
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        message = "This is an XHR POST request"
        # Here we can access the POST data
        print request.POST
else:
    message = "No XHR"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

The Index View:

```
def index(request):
    polylist = [] 
    return render_to_response('test.html', {'polylist': polylist},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The URLConf:

```
(r'^gi_prototype/', 'world.views.index'),
(r'^get_selections$', 'world.views.get_selections')
```

Relevant settings:

```
APPEND_SLASH = 'false'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

When I click on "Link" in the page, the page reloads and an exception is thrown.
The exception, both in Firebug and in Firefox Error Console:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 >(NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 >(NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8000/site_media/jquery-1.5.js :: anonymous :: line 7207"  data: no]

The Django Dev Server provides this output (token replaced with question marks by me):

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'??????????????????????????????']}>
[22/Feb/2011 16:31:23] "POST /get_selections HTTP/1.1" 200 27
[22/Feb/2011 16:31:23] "GET /gi_prototype/ HTTP/1.1" 200 970
```

After several hours of searching, I have begun to think this is simply a limitation of the Django Dev Server, but that seems foolish. Any other suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just `$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()` ?

Comment: I just did it the first way that came to mind. I'm not getting a 403 error, so I don't think this is the problem, but I can give it a shot.

Comment: I edited this post to match your suggestion. The same result occurs, but at least there's one line less javascript. ;)

Comment: What shows net panel of firebug? What response server returns?

Comment: The Net panel shows the POST being sent, and the server returns the 200 27 response. The Net panel also shows the GET response for the index (gi_prototype) as well as the GET response loading JQuery. The Django server output is at the bottom of my question. I don't understand why it's also responding to a GET request, that doesn't make a lot of sense since I am only sending a POST.

Answer (score 2):

So I discovered the answer after many long hours of research, and many would do well to learn from my pain.

The problem lay here:

```
<a href="" onclick='postTest()'>Link</a>
```

XMLHttpRequests, no matter what their wrapper, cannot be initiated through an onclick in a link tag with an href.  I merely changed the code to this:

```
<form><input type='button' value='Link' onclick='postTest()'/></form>
```

And it worked perfectly. No server problem. No AJAX errors. Just a matter of using the correct markup.

Heed the warnings of my tale of woe, lest ye suffer my same fate!

Comment: Your onclick function should return false, otherwise the link will be followed. That is why you see a get on the network panel.

Comment: it would make sense imo if you used jQuery bindings IMO. return false or event.preventDefault() are useful in this case.

Comment: Both of these suggestions would have solved my problem. What I didn't understand at the time was that an href="" points to the same page and basically initiates a request to reload the page.